# how to get given value from dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Lets say a dataframe DF looks like

```
record_id species  wgt
33321      DM      44
33322      DO      58
33323      PB      45
```

If I wanted to get the value for `wgt` when `record_id==33323` and `species=='PB'`, then what do we have to type in Pandas? Something like

```
DF[species=='PB'][record_id==33323]?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DF.loc[(DF.record_id == 33323) & (DF.species == 'PB'), 'wgt']

2    45
Name: wgt, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for filter method.

```
DF[(DF.species=='PB') & (DF.record_id==33323)]['wgt'] 

2    45
Name: wgt, dtype: int64

Use this to get only value
list(DF[(DF.species=='PB') & (DF.record_id==33323)]['wgt'].values) 
[45]
```

Comment: if the answer works, please consider accepting it, you could also upvote.